# connect to an existing blockchain by azure

Tags: azure, ibm-cloud, blockchain, azure-blockchain-service

when creating a blockchain in azure, it has two choice for us ; create a new blockchain or an existing one. my question is that can we become a node of another existing blockchain out of azure( e.g. on IBM cloud) or it just can have a simple connection to that blockchain ?

in blocktalk videos they tried just to connect to an azure blockchain